# Cannot receive '\0' character over UART

Tags: python, c, avr, microprocessors

I am currently working on a project that requires me to send instructions from Python to a microprocessor using UART. The problem I am having however is that I do not seem to be able to identify/receive a '\0' character at the end of the string and therefore I have no way of telling when the string ends on the microprocessor side.

I have tried a simple echo (send character back right after receiving it) so I know that the communication works.

Here is the interrupt function for reading UART:

```
char data[10];
volatile uint8_t charIndex = 0;
volatile uint8_t dataComplete = 0;

ISR(USART1_RX_vect){
    if(dataComplete == 0){
        char input = UDR1;
        if(input == '\0'){
            send('X');
            charIndex = 0;
            dataComplete = 1;
        }
        else{
            data[charIndex] = input;
            charIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the microprocessor to send a X character over UART but that does not happen. I am not sure where the problem is.

EDIT: I tried adding '\0' to '\r' but it has the same negative result. I also tried using a proper serial communicator (Termite) for this task but even with that I am not able to get anything back.

Comment: Too many pieces are missing. My recommendation is to attach the scope and see precisely what's on the wire.

Comment: "I do not seem to be able to identify/recieve a '\0' character at the end of the string" --> perhaps the sending side never sends the _null character_.

Comment: With another string terminator for example % works? I'm asking because afaik there is no '\0' at the end of string in Python.

Comment: Are you sure \0 charater is sent? Can you take a screenshot from Termite in hex mode?